# Setting ethernet controller register in dpdk

Tags: linux, ethernet, dpdk

I am trying to set some registers of the ethernet controller in the DPDK environment, but I can't find the corresponding API to do this. is there any API in the DPDK library for configuring the ethernet controller registers?